# HTML5 Input type datetime-local takes min-width in Table td

Tags: html, html-table

When I put HTML5 Input type "datetime-local" in a Table td, it takes some min-width and becomes non responsive when we adjust the screen size. Here is my code

```
    <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive table-hover">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Sample" /></td>
                <td><input type="datetime-local" class="form-control"  value=""/></td>
                <td><input type="datetime-local"  class="form-control"  value=""/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Sample" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

But when I put the same control in Div it is responsive and works fine.

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:10px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Sample" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Sample" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

But I want to use the Table. How can I use HTML5 Input type "datetime-local "control in Table and be responsive?

Answer (score 0):

Add one more `<div class="table-responsive"></div>` inside container you can solve this problem...........

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Sample" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" value="" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" value="" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Sample" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it but not working, still it takes some min width 247px for the control.

Comment: Bootstrap used minimum  media query at 320 px and  480 px ! so whenever you stack with this view port or you have larger then table size, then you will get a horizontal bar at table bottom...

Comment: Yes, I checked by writing media query and set min-width to control. Still that doesn't work.